# What is the interpretation of $|\langle AB\rangle|$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation, complex-numbers

what is the interpretation of $|\langle AB \rangle|$ ? 
since $|\langle AB \rangle|^2 = \langle AB \rangle [\langle AB \rangle]^\dagger$ , could $|\langle AB \rangle| = \sqrt(|\langle AB \rangle|^2)$ ?

PS. : feel free to correct me

Comment: Your question is rather unclear - please use clearer notation, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) wherever necessary.

Comment: Should this be migrated to math?

Comment: What is $\langle AB \rangle$? Is it the expectation value of the product of two observables? Is it a misnotated inner product of two states (which should be written $\langle A | B \rangle$)? More generally, are $A$ and $B$ states, operators, observables, or something else entirely?

Comment: yes it is the expectation value of the operator AB , calculated on some system state $|\psi \rangle$ . when we generally type $\langle AB \rangle$ , it generally means the expectation  value of the product of two operators A and B

Answer (score 1):

$| \langle AB \rangle|=|\langle \Psi|AB|\Psi \rangle|$ for some operators $A,B$ acting on *state* $|\Psi \rangle$. Using for example a position representation of $A,B$ we can use a wave function i.e. $\Psi= \langle q|\Psi \rangle$ where $|q \rangle$ is a position eigenket (in some dimension, nothing is specified so it is hard to imagine the dimensionality of the problem 1D, 3D etc.). Then we get:

$| \langle A_{pos}B_{pos} \rangle|=|\int\Psi^* A_{pos} B_{pos}\Psi d^3x|$ where $A_{pos}$is the position representation of the operator $A$. If $A$ already is in position representation, i.e. $\hat{x}=x,\hat{p}=-i\hbar \partial_x$ for 1D then you could say $A_{pos}=A$ and ignore the first part.

Clearly a lot of information missing and this is the only answer I can provide unfortunately.

Comment: But $|\langle AB \rangle |$ is not same as the expectation of the operator AB calculated on some system state $| \psi \rangle$ , it should mean something else right ?

Comment: No it is. You can just calculate with expectations since they are numbers.

Comment: thats's why i am asking how do i interpret this , as modulus of some complex number or square root of the $l_2$ norm , i.e , the square root of $||AB |\Psi \rangle||^2$ ?

Comment: how can $|\langle AB \rangle |$ be equal to  $\langle AB \rangle $ ?

Comment: That is only true if $AB$ is Hermitian, so that the expectation value is real!

Comment: if we take A = H , hamiltonian and $B = |\psi_0\rangle \langle \psi_0|$ , then $H |\psi_0\rangle \langle \psi_0 |$ will not be Hermitian , even though they  separately are , in that case how should I interpret $|\langle AB \rangle|$ ?

Comment: It is just the modulus of a complex number (expectation value) in that case